# SQL agent job cannot execute PowerShell command or script

Tags: powershell, agent

SQL agent job cannot execute PowerShell command or script.

1. put a command or a script into job step, eg.
   Write-Host "Hello world"
2. Run job
3. In the job history, I only can see the message like:
   Executed as user: xxx. The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

I can run any command or PowerShell script in Windows PowerShell, the version is:
Version          : 5.1.14393.3866

PS C:\Program Files\xxx\PSScript> Get-InstalledModule
Version    Name                                Repository

---

1.4.7      PackageManagement                   PSGallery
2.2        Posh-SSH                            PSGallery
2.2.4.1    PowerShellGet                       PSGallery
21.1.18226 SqlServer                           PSGallery

Does anyone know what is the problem? thanks.

Comment: Write-host only produces console output. Try write-output and see what it says

Comment: HI Doug, thanks for the quick answer. This works for me, but the questions is, my PowerShell script includes so many output using Write-Host, and the script seems not running properly finally, but in history, only appears "The step did not generate any output. Process Exit Code 0. The step succeeded.".

Comment: Write-Host is ONLY for the console. So if no one is watching the script run, it's not going to be userful. The console meaning the actual powershell window, in case that wasn't clear. Run this test `Write-Host Hello world | set-content c:\temp\outputtest.txt` and you'll see Hello world in your console but there will be no file. That is because it only goes to the console.